# -relationship between a function and a tangent line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function at $x=a$. Show that $f$ has derivate at $x=a$ iff there's only a $L(x) = m(x-a)+b $ such that 
$$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a} = 0 $$

$\Longrightarrow  f $ has derivate at $x=a$ and is continuous at $x=a$ then we can consider $L(x)= f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$ that line works.

$\Longleftarrow$ we know $f$ is continuous at $x=a$and there's just a line such that $$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a} = 0 $$ so 
$$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-(f(a)-L(x))}{x-a} = 0 $$
$$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(a)-L(x)}{x-a} = 0 $$ then I have to see $$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(a)-L(x)}{x-a} = l , l\in \mathbb{R}$$ I don't know what to do next?? some help?

---

a Solution :

we know $ \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a) $ (continuous function at $x=a$) and there's only a $L(x) = m(x-a)+b $ (the only one )such that 
$$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a} = 0 $$

then  $ \lim_{x \to a}f(x)-L(x) = f(a)-b$ (here used "continuous function at $x=a$" )  and  $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)-L(x)= \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{(x-a)} (x-a) = \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a} \lim_{x \to a}(x-a) = 0 $$ at the last used $ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a} = 0 $,then It's necessary $b=f(a)$, then again $$ 0=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a}= \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-m(x-a)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} - m $$ then exists $f'(a)$

Comment: Do you mean _only one line passing through $(a,f(a))$_ ?

Comment: for $\Longleftarrow $ (second part) I know $f$ cont at $a$ and there's a unique $L(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-L(x)}{x-a} = 0$ from there I have to show that $f$ has derivate at $x=a$. from the beginning I don't know how is $L(x)$

Comment: Where did you find this statement ?

Comment: why? matter where it out. I can take $b=f(a)$ and then the second limit is equal $m$, then $l = m$ and I know that $m \in \mathbb{R}$ exists. but don't know if do this it's right.

Comment: Then you let the line pass through $(a,f(a)) \dots$

Answer (score 1):

I speak of $\,\Leftarrow\,$ of course.

Note that $\,f(x)-L(x)=f(x)-f(a)+f(a)-L(x)$

However you can apply the theorem on the limit of a sum if there exist the limits of the addenda.

Here **you have to prove** the existence of the limit of an addendum.

This argument seems a detail, but is essential.

**Solution:**

From $$f(x)=\frac {f(x)-L(x)}{x-a}(x-a)+L(x)$$ you obtain $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=b$$ thus $$b=f(a)$$ by the continuity of $f$ at $a$ and the uniqueness of the limit.

Then $$\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\frac {f(x)-L(x)}{x-a}+m$$so there exists $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=m$$

Comment: You have to deduce that... (can't say  "Let $L(x)= f(a) + m(x-a)$" at the beginning).  I agree with the rest.

Comment: I know it's silly and obvious , but it is a problem.

Comment: If you write $$\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\frac {f(x)-L(x)}{x-a}+m+\frac {b-f(a)}{x-a}$$ what happens if $b \neq f(a)$ ?

Comment: I read your comment. The problem is when you use limits. at the beginning, we don't know $b$ and we can't say $b=f(a)$ so $b - f(a) = k , k \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac {k}{x-a}= \infty$ and then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}= \infty$. But if we show It's neccesary $b=f(a)$ (We have to deduct this from the premise) then we can used it in our limits. Again, the idea is obvious , make a logical demonstration is the difficulty .

Comment: See my edit after **Solution**.

Comment: no words. You got it.